# How do I get the Method object for a method?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to extend the Method class along the lines of:

```
irb(main):008:0> class A
irb(main):009:1> def a
irb(main):010:2> puts "blah"
irb(main):011:2> end
irb(main):012:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> class Method
irb(main):014:1> def aa
irb(main):015:2> p "hi"
irb(main):016:2> end
irb(main):017:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):018:0> f = A.new
=> #<A:0x54ed4>
irb(main):019:0> A.a
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for A:Class
    from (irb):19
    from :0
irb(main):020:0> f.a
blah
=> nil
irb(main):027:0> f.a.aa
blah
NoMethodError: undefined method `aa' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):27
    from :0
```

As expected, when I `f.a.aa`, the `.aa` is being executed on the return value of `f.a`.  How do I gain access to the Method object which represents `f.a`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method) method... =)

```
f.method(:a).aa
```

Comment: I had no idea that the method method existed.  Handy.  Thanks.

Comment: @squeegy: You just have to be methodological in your research. :)